# Question: Well-Defined Operator between Hilbert Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\;\mathcal B(H,F)\;$ be the set of all bounded linear operators $\;S:H\rightarrow F\;$ where $H,F\;$ are some Hilbert spaces.

To begin with, we consider $\;T_n \in \mathcal B(H,F)\;\forall n\;$ to be a Cauchy sequence. Then $\forall x \in H\;\;\vert\vert T_nx-T_mx \vert\vert \le \vert \vert T_n-T_m \vert \vert\cdot \vert \vert x \vert \vert \;$ which implies $\;T_nx\;$ is a Cauchy sequence on $F\;$. Since $\;F$ is Banach space, one can find $\;y \in F\;$ such that $T_nx \rightarrow y$ as $n \to \infty\;$

I want to show there is $\;x \in H\;$ such that $T_x=y\;$. This is why I define $T:H \rightarrow F\;$ as $Tx=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} T_nx\;\forall x \in H\;$.

**My question is: How can I show the above is well defined?**

I took $x,z \in H\;$ such that $\;T_x=T_z\; \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} T_nx=\lim_{n \to \infty} T_nz\;$

How do I proceed? I believe the answer is obvious but I 've been stuck. I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're saying is you want to show $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} T_n x$ exists and is unique for each $x$.  You found the limit using completeness, and it is unique because of uniqueness of limits in $F$ (since it's a metric space and has all of those nice properties that topological spaces can have).

Comment: Thank you very much! It was extremely simple! I guess I should have a break from studying :)